# Mathjax formular causes linebreak with other elements

Tags: html, angular, mathjax

I am a beginner in angular and need to get mathjax to work on our website, which loads predefined latex formula dynamically from the backend.

For this I am using the package [mathjax-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjax-angular) and managed to get the formula typesetted correctly. However the typesetting causes a linebreak for each formula, such that the formula texts and checkboxes are not inline anymore.

[image]

Maybe there is some setting in the imports for MathjaxModule in the app.module.ts that I am missing?

This is in the app.module.ts

```
MathjaxModule.forRoot({
  config: {
    loader: {
      load: ["output/svg", "[tex]/require", "[tex]/ams", 'input/tex-base', 'ui/menu']
    },
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [["$$", "$$"]],
      packages: ["base", "require", "ams"],
      processEscapes: false
    },
    svg: { fontCache: "global" }
  },
  src: "https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
}),
```

This is the html

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let item of shuffledArray; let i =
    <label formArrayName="options" [ngClass]="{correctAnswer: (answerSubmitted && !answerCorrect && selectedMultipleChoiceAnswers[i] && item[1][2])}" [ngClass]="{incorrectAnswer: (answerSubmitted && !answerCorrect && selectedMultipleChoiceAnswers[i] && !item[1][2])}"
      style="padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 22px;text-indent: -30px;">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        [formControlName]="i"
        [checked]="false"
        value="{{item[0]}}"
        style="margin-left: 10px;"
      />
      <span [mathjax]= "item[1][0]" class="htmlChoice" style="padding-left: 5px;"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: A stackblitz of this would be ideal in order to inspect the cause of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line break issue you are experiencing is likely due to MathJax injecting a `div` element around each rendered formula. This is the default behavior of MathJax when it processes inline math.

To fix this issue, you can try wrapping the MathJax directive in a `span` element with the `display: inline-block` CSS property set. This will ensure that the MathJax element remains inline with the other elements.

Here is an example:

```html
<span style="display: inline-block;">
  <span [mathjax]="item[1][0]"></span>
</span>
```

This should prevent MathJax from adding a line break after the formula. You may need to adjust the CSS properties to fit your specific layout needs.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved – or worked-around – my problem too, using Quarto.

Answer (score 2):

The solution by Asaduzzaman Atik is correct in principle, but in this special case it is a simple misunderstanding of the latex syntax: $$ is for displayed formulae whereas $ is for inline formulae.

Simply changing your source to $formula$ will fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

By combining Beginners suggestion and Asaduzzaman Atik, i am able to get mathjax formulas and normal textes rendered inline with other elements by setting up some css properties

```
<div class="htmlChoice"  [mathjax] ="item[1][0]" style="padding-left: 30px; top: -20px; position: relative;"></div>
```